# Why does recursion return the first call in the stack and not the last?

Tags: java, recursion

I cant for the life of me figure out why this returns 0 rather than 5. "i" keeps getting incremented before it hits the last return statement, however it always returns 0, from the first call in the stack. I would think that since the most recent call on the stack hits the return in the block "i == 5" first it would return and print 5.

**Returns 0**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(incrementI(0));
}       


public static int incrementI(int i) {
    if (i == 5){
        return i;           
    } else {
         incrementI(i + 1);
    }

    return i;       
}
```

**Returns 5**

```
public static int incrementI(int i) {
    if (i == 5){
        return i;           
    } else {
        return incrementI(i + 1);
    }               
}
```

Comment: java !== javascript

Comment: What's `something()` ?? Is that supposed to be `incrementI()`?

Comment: What does `something(int i)` do?

Comment: Where is the recursion?

Comment: Yes, something is suppose to be inrementI(), quick typo, Thanks!

Comment: I should stick to sites like programmers and code review. Maybe stack overflow is too elementary for questions like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine you wrote such function:

```
public static int square(int x) {
    pow(x, 2);
    return x;
}
```

It will compute the square of `x`. But then computed square will not affect anything and the function will return just x.

Now look carefully at your code

```
if (i == 5){
    return i;           
} else {
    something(i + 1);
}
return i;
```

If `i` is not `5`, `something(i + 1)` will be called. Then it will return some value but this value will not affect to anything. And then `incrementI` function will return just `i`, in your case it's `0`.

Comment: something is suppose to be inrementI(), quick typo!

Comment: @NightSkyCode, Looks like you're missing Pavel's point.  The `incrementI(i)` function in your first example always returns `i`:  It immediately returns `5` if `i==5`, otherwise it does some stuff, and then it returns `i`.  It doesn't matter what "some stuff" is.  It doesn't matter whether "some stuff" is a function call named `something()` or whether it is a recursive call to `incrementI()`.  Either way, it does whatever, and then it ignores the result of doing whatever, and then it returns `i`.